# Concatenate using javascript into validation error message

Tags: javascript

I´m trying to concatenate error messages from javascript validation, i have the updateErrorMessage wich receives just one message and display the modal (with just one message per time):

How can i concatenate all error messages to display all them at once into the modal window?

```
function updateErrorMessage(msg) {
    var errorMessage = msg;
    var modal = document.querySelector('.modal-wrap');
    document.getElementById('close').onclick = function() {
        removeClass(modal, 'md-active');
    }

    document.getElementById('modalErrormessage').innerHTML = errorMessage;
    addClass(modal, 'md-active');
}
```

EDIT: I do capture the error message this way:

```
if (Protocol != '' && Protocol.length < 11) {
    formatErrorMessage('wrong protocol');
    updateErrorMessage('Please! correct protocol.');
    e.preventDefault(e);
    e.stopPropagation(e);
}
```

I try to use push but I do get undefined error message:

```
EDIT: 
function formatErrorMessage(msg){
    var errorMessage = msg;
    var textMsg = [];
    textMsg.push(errorMessage);
    var finalErrorMessage;
    mensagemErroFinal = textMsg.join(', ');
    return mensagemErroFinal;

}
```

Comment: string concatenation uses `+` not `.`. `console.log('errorMessage  ' + textMsg);` Can you provide a fiddle with your problem?

Comment: You can set multiple parameters: `console.log('errorMessage  ', textMsg);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Comment: i am using for the modal this codepen: http://codepen.io/jhoward/pen/HkLbi

Comment: This is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qkw4ho85/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push will add to array, you need to use .join to join the elements of an array into a string. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Also, the reason you are receiving an undefined error for that console log is because you are using PHP syntax to add the textMsg. You must use + like this: `console.log('errorMessage  ' + textMsg);`

Comment: Can i try to call: document.getElementById('modalErrormessage').innerHTML = formatErrorMessage();

Comment: Technically, yes, but you need to return your textMsg. You would end your function with `return textMsg;`

Comment: I just edit the formatErrorMessage function, now the console.log display the messages, but the modal display "undefined"

Comment: That's because you're trying to join your array with your array as the separator. This line `mensagemErroFinal = textMsg.join(textMsg);` should be something like `mensagemErroFinal = textMsg.join(' ');` where the separator here is a space

Comment: the solution was using a variable errorMsg.push('<br>A nice error message'); instead of a function.